# The most effective way to check if an Elasticsearch document exists with the given values

Tags: java, elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-java-api

I want to check if there are any Elasticsearch documents that exist with specified values. Where is the fastest way to check because I just want to check for existence.
I am looking for implementation in java.

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem? was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a query in the filter context (see [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/query-filter-context.html)), because Elasticsearch won't calculate the matching score and will cache the result. Using the query DSl, the query might look like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "the_field_name": "the_value_to_match"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As for the Java API, you'll find your answer in the Elastic documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-compound-queries.html#java-query-dsl-bool-query